# How to get Tag List for a particular post type in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I wanted to print tag list for my particular post type page. I used every function to fetch tags. but it is giving me all the tag list including used in other posts types.

Answer (score 4):

```
<!-- begin custom related loop, isa -->

<?php 

// get the custom post type's taxonomy terms

$custom_taxterms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'your_taxonomy', array('fields' => 'ids') );
// arguments
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 3, // you may edit this number
'orderby' => 'rand',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $custom_taxterms
    )
),
'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
);
$related_items = new WP_Query( $args );
// loop over query
if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
echo '<ul>';
while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();
?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: my question is for particular post types. not for a single post. so this is not useful for my case

Comment: If you pass ur post type value as post _tag value in   wp_get_object_terms( $post_ids, 'post_tag', $optional_args ); you get the results.Kindly refer the link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms

Comment: @priya you should read the documentation properly. The link you gave, clearly mentions that 'post_tag' argument must be a taxonomy. you can not pass post type there.

Answer (score 0):

For creating filter type of widget. this must be required to fetch tag list as per the post types.

for that, I created one generic function by you can list tags or any taxonomy list as per the post type.

function get_terms_by_post_type( $taxo_term, $post_types ) {

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
                            "SELECT term.*, COUNT(*) from $wpdb->terms AS term
                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS texo ON term.term_id = texo.term_id
                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = texo.term_taxonomy_id
                            INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts AS post ON post.ID = tr.object_id
                            WHERE post.post_type IN('%s') AND texo.taxonomy IN('%s')
                            GROUP BY term.term_id",
                            join( "', '", $post_types ),
                            join( "', '", $taxo_term)
                        );

$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
return $results;
```

}

Call this Function and pass taxonomy term and post type. it will give you an array of tags.